# Calculating the resulting phase from its complex $x$ and $y$ field components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]

Suppose I have multiple light sources in a 2 dimension plane (X and Y), for which I only know the real and imaginary component of the electric field in the X and Y directions within the 2D plane.
This image is an example of such a case. There is 3 sources S1,s2,s3 and I only know the electric fields $\vec{Ex}=A+Bi$ and $\vec{Ey}=C+Di$ at points within the plane where A,B,C and D are constants. Suppose I wish to find out what the phase of the resulting waveform is at (x1,y1), is this possible with the available information? Calculating the phase of individual components I believe would be tan inverse of the imaginary/real component. Would the components of the wave($\vec{Ex}$ and $\vec{Ey}$) have a different phase and what would they mean? What would this phase be in relation to phase of the two components?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to explain your notation. $\vec E$ appears to be a function of position, but what is its domain - what does it map each position to ? Are $A,B,C,D$ constants ? Are they functions of position ? Are they functions of position and time ? The obvious answer is $\vec E(x,y) = (A+Bi, C+Di)$, but that seems too simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your three light sources emit coherent waves which combine to produce oscillating E field components at each point in the region, and the phase of these oscillations (relative to some chosen reference time) is represented by vectors rotating in the complex number plane.  The A,B,C, and D represent instantaneous values for the components of these vectors.  These imaginary vectors are similar to those used to represent voltages in an AC circuit. The magnitude of the oscillations of the electric field components at each point would be given by the square root of the real part of the phase vector squared plus the imaginary part squared, and the phase by the arc-tangent as you suggested. The resultant electric field vector would rotate  the xy plane. If the phase difference between the two electric field components is $90^o$, the resultant vector will sweep out an ellipse. If the two are in phase, the result is a straight line. Other phase differences give intermediate shapes.

Comment: From what I gather, the resulting polarisation is explained by the Jones vector? I believe the magnitude of the resulting oscillation of the two components would be the square root of the sum of the magnitude of the individual components. What would the absolute phase of the resultant field be?

Comment: I think the maximum value of the resultant field would depend on the phase difference.

Comment: The phase of the resultant  rotating field cold be described in terms of either of its components.